# AjaxForm Submit posting empty values

Tags: javascript, php, ajaxform

I have a strange issue with AjaxForm Submit. Project that i have to debug should upload selected file to the server (PHP) using Ajax so upload progress can be tracked. I made sure my php.ini allows POST and Upload sizes of 100+ MB, max_execution_time of 5 mins. Regardless of all that, if i upload a file of less than 9 MB (including 8.9 MB) everything is fine, file is uploaded. 9 MB is "sometimes works sometimes won't) and everything above 10 MB is guaranteed to cause issues.
In the code below (short version) i'll put comment to the place that's causing issues, please let me know what you think it could be:

HTML (omitted some things like progress bar to make code easy to read):

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="publisher-box-focus">
      ...controls for choosing a file etc....
     <button type="button" onclick="Wo_GetPRecordLink()" id="publisher- 
            button"><span>Share</span></button>
     <input type="hidden" name="hash_id" value="some_generated_id_is_here">
</form>
```

JS:

```
function Wo_GetPRecordLink() {
     $('form.post').submit();
}

$('form.post').ajaxForm({
    url: '<url>/myPhp.php',
    beforeSend: function () {
      var percentVal = '0%';
      bar.width(percentVal);
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) { ***This works fine
      var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
      bar.width(percentVal);
      $('#progress').slideDown(200);
      percent.html(percentVal); 
    },
    success: function (data) {
      if(data.status == 200) {
        //My PHP does return 200 after file upload is complete but it gets incomplete POST
             data thus sends no data response i'm expecting!
      } 
    }
  });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$hash_id = '';
if (!empty($_POST['hash_id'])) {
    $hash_id = $_POST['hash_id'];
}
echo "HASH IS: ".$hash_id; //*****HERE when uploading big files (and only files > 9MB 
 $hash_id is empty even thou Chrome Inspector shows that hidden input value is set 
 properly! This happens only for files bigger than 9 MB!
...
```

Have you every had this kind of issue? Do you have an idea what might be causing it?

Server is ec2 Amazon instance.

PHP version 5.5.38

Comment: you are missing method type. $("#theForm").ajaxForm({url: 'server.php', type: 'post'})

Comment: hmmm didn't help :(

Comment: is everything work fine in local environment?

Comment: hmmm i have only this version deployed on the website as its a complex system and i just got to "fix few bugs"

Answer (score 0):

If your server settings are correct, there is a problem in ajax post method.

Please dont forget file input name attribute :)

Can you try this?

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="publisher-box-focus">
  ...controls for choosing a file etc....
 <input type="hidden" name="hash_id" value="some_generated_id_is_here">
 <button type="button" onclick="Wo_GetPRecordLink(event)" id="publisher-button"><span>Share</span></button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function Wo_GetPRecordLink(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<url>/myPhp.php',
        data: $('#publisher-box-focus').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            $('#progress').slideDown(200);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 200) {
            
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hmmm nope, still the same :(